# linking std::experimental::filesystem with Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, macos, c++17

I am using std::experimental::filesystem with Xcode 9.0 beta.  The compiler phase completes OK but the linker complains of undefined symbols:

```
std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path::__filename() const
std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path::__filename() const
std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path::__stem() const
std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__status(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path const&, std::__1::error_code*)
```

I am also using std::experimental::filesystem::canonical(), but the linker isn't complaining about that being missing.

How can I configure the project to include these missing references?

UPDATE:

I have been experimenting with a simpler program.  If I just use canonical() then the linker complains that it is missing.

I can use std::experimental::optional - everything compiles, links and runs OK.  But 'optional' is a template and so probably doesn't involve a library.

Comment: Update: the filesystem header was completely removed in Xcode 9 beta 4.

Comment: Is there any way to use filesystem on xcode 9 ??
Must i go back to boost (which is not std conform because it lacks the important u8string method in path class).

Comment: @Lothar it seems yes, I'm waiting for this feature and I heard that Xcode 9.1 will include filesystem header, but I'm not sure exactly...

Answer (score 1):

Are you compiling with any `-std=` option ("C++ Language Dialect" option in Xcode)?

Comment: I tried the C++17 dialect and the different library options.  Neither fixed the issue.