# Using c++ experimental filesystem in Xcode project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

My Xcode project contains C++ static libraries that compiled for iOS.
The C++ code includes `<experimental/filesystem>` that is not part of the Xcode C++ lib. I manage to compile the c++ code to **static lib** with Xcode 9-beta command line tools (With Xcode 8.3.3 I didn't manage to compile the c++ code since filesystem was not part of c++ lib).

When including the static lib in my project I'm getting:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__status(std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path..

This is not specific arm64 issue. Probably need to use C++ lib with this implementation or include filesystem lib but didn't manage to find a way to do it.
Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681703/linking-stdexperimentalfilesystem-with-xcode-9