# How to use C++17 features on mac OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, c++17

I would like to use all the features of C++ 17, but more specifically, I need `std::(experimental)::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` available in C++17, how do I get to use it?

I am using Eclipse CDT on Mac OSX (I am also comfortable with xCode, if necessary), and I want to use C++17.

Thanks

sources:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator/recursive_directory_iterator

Comment: You need a compiler that supports C++17 and can run on your system.

Comment: I don't think you'll have much success with Xcode and filesystem yet.  It partly appeared and then disappeared: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44681703

Answer (score 0):

You can use gcc and you can install with this line.

`brew install gcc --HEAD`

This gcc has limited support for C++17 also it can be enabled by `-std=c++17.`